# Google Analytics finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, google-analytics, build.gradle

I'm trying to implement `google analytics` in my Android app, I have added the .jar file to `libs` folder and in gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/analytic.jar')
    ........
}
```

But when I try to run my app, it gets this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev116-1.20.0'
}
```

Follow latest [API guidelines](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analytics/v3).
There is no need of jar etc.. just use above only.

Comment: I have added that depencencie but I can't import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares Please check your google play library is updated

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares follow setup guidelines https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Comment: same error with 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev116-1.20.0'

Comment: have you checked in SDK Manager that Google play services library is updated?

Comment: yes is updated, could this error be for other library conflict?

Comment: If I have added the whole library of Play services as dependencie, I have to add analytics library too? @strike

Comment: I'll try my best to share AndroidStudio code with you in the morning.